# how to declare variables for s3 backend in terraform?

Tags: variables, amazon-s3, runtime, terraform

s3.tf

```
terraform {
backend "s3" {
bucket = "some-bucket"
key = "path/to/key"
region = "some-aws-region" 
}}
```

How to pass the bucket and region values to this from a variables.tf file?

Answer (score 50):

hello here's a solution :

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
  }
}
```

pass the backend like that  and then :

on the terraform init command :

```
terraform init \
-backend-config="bucket=${TFSTATE_BUCKET}" \
-backend-config="key=${TFSTATE_KEY}" \
-backend-config="region=${TFSTATE_REGION}"
```

you should use env  to  set `TFSTATE_BUCKET TFSTATE_KEY and TFSTATE_REGION`

here's a link of the docs : [the Terraform docs on "Partial Configuration" of Backends](https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/config.html#partial-configuration)

Comment: Good answer! I think it would be even better if it included a link to [the Terraform docs on "Partial Configuration" of Backends](https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/config.html#partial-configuration) 

Comment: @MartinAtkins thank you , yes you're right i will add the link to the answer :)

Comment: I can't believe this is a constraint... It's a very stupid limitation if you want to maintain multiple stages. It basically means that I have to either create a separate batch script for each terraform command, or that I'll have to duplicate the terraform scripts. Who thought that this was a good idea..?

Comment: Terragrunt has created a wrapper which can better handle multiple backends. Additional information on their blog https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/features/keep-your-remote-state-configuration-dry/

Answer (score 18):

[Montassar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63051134/4477336) is quite good, but I prefer file version:

1. Create `dev.conf` file

   ```
   bucket="some-bucket"
   region="some-aws-region"
   ```
2. Remove those properties in `main.tf`,

   ```
   terraform {
    backend "s3" {
     key = "path/to/key"
   }}
   ```
3. Run init:

   ```sh
   terraform init -backend-config=dev.conf
   ```

[Terrform Source](https://www.terraform.io/language/settings/backends/configuration#partial-configuration)

Comment: I do prefer this solution too. But I name my file `dev.tfbackend`, using the recommended naming pattern of the documentation you linked.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is not currently possible as if you add a variable interpolation in that, you will get an error

> terraform.backend: configuration cannot contain interpolations